# Fixing an issue with my humanized time method?

Tags: c#, .net

Since there are none out there already, except the ones in large Nuget packages that only 0.5% of the features get used, or ones that just aren't 100% humanized format, I decided to write my own.

It all works well, up until the point the timeSpan's total seconds reached 3720 (I think)

I noticed when it should of said "1 hour, and 2 minutes" it said "1 hour, 1 minute and 60 seconds". I understand that this code is getting a little complicated and I'm unsure why its going wrong.

Can anyone help me fix this?

```
public static string GetHumanizedTime(DateTime dateTime)
{
    var timeSpan = DateTime.Now - dateTime;

    var hours = timeSpan.TotalHours.RoundDown();
    var minutes = timeSpan.TotalMinutes.RoundDown();
    var seconds = timeSpan.TotalSeconds.RoundDown();

    var secondsAfterMinutes = seconds - minutes * 60;
    var secondsAfterHours = seconds - hours * 3600;

    var minutesAfterSeconds = minutes - hours * 60;
    var minutesAfterHours = minutes - hours * 60;

    if (seconds < 60)
    {
        return $"{seconds} second{(seconds != 1 ? "s" : "")}";
    }

    if (seconds >= 60 && minutes < 60)
    {
        if (secondsAfterMinutes < 1)
        {
            return $"{minutes} minute{(minutes != 1 ? "s" : "")}";
        }

        return $"{minutes} minute{(minutes != 1 ? "s" : "")} and {secondsAfterMinutes} second{(secondsAfterMinutes != 1 ? "s" : "")}";
    }

    if (minutes >= 60 && hours < 24)
    {
        if (minutesAfterHours > 0)
        {
            if (secondsAfterHours > 0)
            {
                return $"{hours} hour{(hours != 1 ? "s" : "")}, {minutesAfterSeconds} minute{(minutesAfterSeconds != 1 ? "s" : "")} and {secondsAfterHours} second{(secondsAfterHours != 1 ? "s" : "")}";
            }
            else
            {
                return $"{hours} hour{(hours != 1 ? "s" : "")}, and {minutesAfterSeconds} minute{(minutesAfterSeconds != 1 ? "s" : "")}";
            }
        }

        if (secondsAfterHours > 0)
        {
            return $"{hours} hour{(hours != 1 ? "s" : "")}, and {secondsAfterHours} second{(secondsAfterHours != 1 ? "s" : "")}";
        }

        return $"{hours} hour{(hours != 1 ? "s" : "")}";
    }

    if (hours >= 24)
    {
        return "TODO days";
    }

    return "TODO";
}
```

I know a few may ask what `RoundDown` is, so I included that too.

```
public static int RoundDown(this double dbl)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(dbl));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't wanna use something like [this](https://github.com/Humanizr/)? They seem have [solved this problem](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/blob/a7a1d956b65aea5b7dedd6e7f05de7d47b123931/src/Humanizer.Tests.Shared/TimeSpanHumanizeTests.cs) If you don't want to take that package as a dependency, maybe check out their source code?

Comment: Why aren't you using the `Minutes` and `Seconds` properties? It seems that you are trying to calculate them yourself.

Comment: Like Ofir Winegarten said use the Seconds and Minutes properties to get the minutes within an hour and seconds with a minute, instead of TotalMinutes and TotalSeconds which are something completely different. This way your code can be shorted because you don’t need to check for >60 and <60 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use an existing library to solve this problem like @jeroenh suggested.

But here is the issue with your code: Your `secondsAfterHours` variable simply keeps count of how many seconds have passed after an hour. So it goes up to 60 and then keeps counting up. This is what gets printed on this line:

```
return $"{hours} hour{(hours != 1 ? "s" : "")}, {minutesAfterSeconds} minute{(minutesAfterSeconds != 1 ? "s" : "")} and {secondsAfterHours} second{(secondsAfterHours != 1 ? "s" : "")}";
```

So you can fix your issue simply by changing that line to

```
return $"{hours} hour{(hours != 1 ? "s" : "")}, {minutesAfterSeconds} minute{(minutesAfterSeconds != 1 ? "s" : "")} and {secondsAfterMinutes} second{(secondsAfterMinutes != 1 ? "s" : "")}";
```

Your fixed code is

```
public static string GetHumanizedTime(DateTime dateTime)
{
    var timeSpan = DateTime.Now - dateTime;

    var hours = timeSpan.TotalHours.RoundDown();
    var minutes = timeSpan.TotalMinutes.RoundDown();
    var seconds = timeSpan.TotalSeconds.RoundDown();

    var secondsAfterMinutes = seconds - minutes * 60;
    var secondsAfterHours = seconds - hours * 3600;

    var minutesAfterSeconds = minutes - hours * 60;
    var minutesAfterHours = minutes - hours * 60;

    if (seconds < 60)
    {
        return $"{seconds} second{(seconds != 1 ? "s" : "")}";
    }

    if (seconds >= 60 && minutes < 60)
    {
        if (secondsAfterMinutes < 1)
        {
            return $"{minutes} minute{(minutes != 1 ? "s" : "")}";
        }

        return $"{minutes} minute{(minutes != 1 ? "s" : "")} and {secondsAfterMinutes} second{(secondsAfterMinutes != 1 ? "s" : "")}";
    }

    if (minutes >= 60 && hours < 24)
    {
        if (minutesAfterHours > 0)
        {
            if (secondsAfterMinutes > 0)
            {
                return $"{hours} hour{(hours != 1 ? "s" : "")}, {minutesAfterSeconds} minute{(minutesAfterSeconds != 1 ? "s" : "")} and {secondsAfterMinutes} second{(secondsAfterMinutes != 1 ? "s" : "")}";
            }
            else
            {
                return $"{hours} hour{(hours != 1 ? "s" : "")}, and {minutesAfterSeconds} minute{(minutesAfterSeconds != 1 ? "s" : "")}";
            }
        }

        if (secondsAfterHours > 0)
        {
            return $"{hours} hour{(hours != 1 ? "s" : "")}, and {secondsAfterHours} second{(secondsAfterHours != 1 ? "s" : "")}";
        }

        return $"{hours} hour{(hours != 1 ? "s" : "")}";
    }

    if (hours >= 24)
    {
        return "TODO days";
    }

    return "TODO";
}
```

This code correctly prints:

```
1 hour, and 59 seconds
1 hour, and 1 minute
1 hour, 1 minute and 1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think @Hele's answer is correct, as its using the seconds from only minutes. I decided to post my fix as I noticed that the `secondsAfterHours` variable didn't take in to account of the minutes.

Changing this line,

```
var secondsAfterHours = seconds - hours * 3600;
```

To this line fixes the issue.

```
var secondsAfterHours = timeInSeconds - minutesAfterHours * 60 - timeInHours * 3600;
```